# GLM dropping an interaction

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, generalized-linear-model, nonlinear-regression, negative-binomial-distribution

can someone help me please?

How can I see the coeficient for municipio6:ano0, considering that I don't want to have a reference level in my model for municipio variable (that's why I set intercept to 0).

```
> m1 <- glm.nb(casos ~ 0 + municipio + ano0 + municipio:ano0 + offset(log(populacao)), data = dataset)
> summary(m1)

Call:
glm.nb(formula = casos ~ 0 + municipio + ano0 + municipio:ano0 + 
    offset(log(populacao)), data = dataset, init.theta = 1.202601993, 
    link = log)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-1.6965  -1.0652  -0.7363   0.3766   4.0045  

Coefficients:
                 Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
municipio6      -12.22419    0.26220 -46.622  < 2e-16 ***
municipio1      -10.07937    0.16096 -62.621  < 2e-16 ***
municipio2      -10.15899    0.16450 -61.758  < 2e-16 ***
municipio3      -11.46408    0.20718 -55.333  < 2e-16 ***
municipio4      -11.12637    0.21401 -51.990  < 2e-16 ***
municipio5      -12.18312    0.26636 -45.739  < 2e-16 ***
ano0              0.06878    0.03153   2.181  0.02916 *  
municipio1:ano0  -0.09080    0.03802  -2.389  0.01692 *  
municipio2:ano0  -0.10842    0.03845  -2.820  0.00480 ** 
municipio3:ano0  -0.06582    0.04144  -1.588  0.11223    
municipio4:ano0  -0.14021    0.04388  -3.196  0.00139 ** 
municipio5:ano0   0.01989    0.04447   0.447  0.65471    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for Negative Binomial(1.2026) family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 24450.50  on 1008  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance:   989.11  on  996  degrees of freedom
AIC: 2863

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 1


              Theta:  1.203 
          Std. Err.:  0.134 

 2 x log-likelihood:  -2837.036
```

Answer (score 6):

You actually need to remove the main effect of `ano0`. So your model formula should be

```r
casos ~ 0 + municipio + municipio:ano0 + 
    offset(log(populacao))
```

I know it looks like you're omitting a term, but you will estimate exactly the same number of parameters and the model fit will be identical. This gives you an intercept and slope of `ano0` for each level of `municipio`.